# How do you document security in GraphQL Authorization?

Tags: .net, security, graphql, graphiql

In GraphQL, people usually use graphiql or similar libraries to provide a documentation of the schema (query / mutations etc...) however, how do you do the same for authentication, authorziation requirements?

I'm using .NET to implement graphql. I used graph.authorization to implement a role based authorization. Is there a way to query these security requirement from the schema or do I have to manually write it as part of my description?